# Salt Generation and open source software

Tags: security, open-source, encryption, salt, rainbowtable

As I understand it, the best practice for generating salts is to use some cryptic formula (or even magic constant) stored in your source code.

I'm working on a project that we plan on releasing as open source, but the problem is that with the source comes the secret formula for generating salts, and therefore the ability to run rainbow table attacks on our site.

I figure that lots of people have contemplated this problem before me, and I'm wondering what the best practice is. It seems to me that there is no point having a salt at all if the code is open source, because salts can be easily reverse-engineered.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Really salts just need to be unique for each entry.  Even if the attacker can calculate what the salt is, it makes the rainbow table extremely difficult to create.  This is because the salt is added to the password before it is hashed, so it effectively adds to the total number of entries the rainbow table must contain to have a list of all possible values for a password field.

Answer (score 246):

*Since questions about salting hashes come along on a quite regular basis and there seems to be quite some confusion about the subject, I extended this answer.*

#### What is a salt?

A salt is a *random* set of bytes of a fixed length that is added to the input of a hash algorithm.

#### Why is salting (or seeding) a hash useful?

Adding a random salt to a hash ensures that the same password will produce many different hashes. The salt is usually stored in the database, together with the result of the hash function.
Salting a hash is good for a number of reasons:

1. Salting greatly increases the difficulty/cost of precomputated attacks (including [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table#Rainbow_tables))
2. Salting makes sure that the same password does not result in the same hash. 
   This makes sure you cannot determine if two users have the same password. And, *even more important*, you cannot determine if the same person uses the same password across different systems.
3. <s>Salting increases the complexity of passwords, thereby greatly decreasing the effectiveness of both</s> [Dictionary-](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack) <s>and</s> [Birthday attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack)<s>.</s> (This is only true if the salt *is* stored separate from the hash).
4. Proper salting *greatly* increases the storage need for precomputation attacks, up to the point where they are no longer practical. (8 character case-sensitive alpha-numeric passwords with 16 bit salt, hashed to a 128 bit value, would take up [just under 200](http://www.google.com/search?q=62%5E8+*+2%5E16+*+128+bits+%3D) [exabytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exabyte) without rainbow reduction).

#### There is no need for the salt to be secret.

A salt is not a secret key, instead a salt 'works' by making the hash function specific to each instance. With salted hash, there is not *one* hash function, but one for every possible salt value. This prevent the attacker from attacking *N* hashed passwords for less than *N* times the cost of attacking one password. This is the point of the salt.
A "secret salt" is not a salt, it is called a "key", and it means that you are no longer computing a hash, but a [Message Authentication Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) (MAC). Computing MAC is tricky business (much trickier than simply slapping together a key and a value into a hash function) and it is a very different subject altogether.

The salt **must be random** for every instance in which it is used. This ensures that an attacker has to attack every salted hash separately.
If you rely on your salt (or salting algorithm) being secret, you enter the realms of [Security Through Obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity#Arguments_against) (won't work). Most probably, you do not get additional security from the salt secrecy; you just get the warm fuzzy feeling of security. So instead of making your system more secure, it just distracts you from reality.

#### So, why does the salt have to be random?

Technically, the salt should be *unique*. The point of the salt is to be distinct for each hashed password. This is meant *worldwide*. Since there is no central organization which distributes unique salts on demand, we have to rely on the next best thing, which is random selection with an unpredictable random generator, preferably within a salt space large enough to make collisions improbable (two instances using the same salt value).

It is tempting to try to derive a salt from some data which is "presumably unique", such as the user ID, but such schemes often fail due to some nasty details:

1. If you use **for example the user ID**, some bad guys, attacking distinct systems, may just pool their resources and create precomputed tables for user IDs 1 to 50. A user ID is unique *system-wide* but not *worldwide*.
2. The same applies to the **username**: there is one "root" per Unix system, but there are many roots in the world. A rainbow table for "root" would be worth the effort, since it could be applied to millions of systems. Worse yet, there are also many "bob" out there, and many do not have sysadmin training: their passwords could be quite weak.
3. Uniqueness is also temporal. Sometimes, users change their password. For each **new password**, a **new salt** must be selected. Otherwise, an attacker obtained the hash of the old password and the hash of the new could try to attack both simultaneously.

Using a random salt obtained from a cryptographically secure, unpredictable PRNG may be some kind of overkill, but at least it *provably* protects you against all those hazards. It's not about preventing the attacker from knowing what an *individual* salt is, it's about not giving them the big, fat target that will be used on a substantial number of potential targets. Random selection makes the targets as thin as is practical.

#### In conclusion:

Use a random, evenly distributed, high entropy salt. Use a new salt whenever you create a new password or change a password. Store the salt along with the hashed password. Favor big salts (at least 10 bytes, preferably 16 or more).

A salt does not turn a bad password into a good password. It just makes sure that the attacker will at least pay the dictionary attack price for *each* bad password he breaks.

*Usefull sources:*
[stackoverflow.com: *Non-random salt for password hashes*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536584/non-random-salt-for-password-hashes/536756#536756)
[Bruce Schneier: *Practical Cryptography*](http://www.schneier.com/book-practical.html) (book)
[Matasano Security: *Enough with the Rainbow Tables*](http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html)
[usenix.org: *Unix crypt used salt since 1976*](http://www.usenix.org/events/usenix99/provos/provos_html/node9.html)
[owasp.org](http://www.owasp.org/): [*Why add salt*](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Hashing_Java#Why_add_salt_.3F)
[openwall.com](http://www.openwall.com/): [*Salts*](http://www.openwall.com/lists/john-users/2005/12/18/1)

*Disclaimer:*
I'm not a security expert. (Although this answer was reviewed by [Thomas Pornin](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/655/))
If any of the security professionals out there find something wrong, please do comment or edit this wiki answer.

Comment: It doesn't have to be random, it just has to be different for each row.

Comment: Yes. They do need to be stored.

Comment: it needs to be different for each row across all machines the system is used, the salt also needs to be unpredictable. This is achieved by creating a random salt. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536584/non-random-salt-for-password-hashes/536756#536756

Comment: @Jacco, this is fantastic. And I agree with your argument for randomness. This is the most effective way to prevent attackers from 'guessing' the salt across all systems. (Though a crypto RNG is definitely overkill).

Comment: "There is no need for the salt to be secret". That is terrible advice. If I know the salt, I can create a rainbow table, and I can do it with a dictionary of 1 million common passwords in a few seconds.

Comment: If you know the salt, you can run a brute force attack on this particular hash. There is no advantage in creating a rainbow table if you want to break a single hash. Also, creating a million hashes for a good hashing scheme will take longer than you seem to assume.

Comment: You should also note, as the Matasano reference emphasizes, that besides a good salt, you need a good algorithm, like bcrypt or sha256 iterated a configurable number of times.  Otherwise, as clarified at http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/ even today folks can do a brute-force attack given the salt of a high percentage of real passwords.

Comment: @nealmcb Thanks for the reply. A salt does not prevent brute-force attacks, it was never supposed to do so. This answer does not touch hashing algorithms or anything else related to password hashing; the salting part turns out to be complicated enough. Also, the article you are referring, although not directly wrong, is quite tendentious: it tries to make a case for adaptive cost hashing algorithms by using weak passwords as an argument.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Do you think weak passwords aren't common, or that adaptive cost hashing algorithms aren't a good idea?  I appreciate the benefits of not straying from the focus of this question, but I see so much bad practice and advice out there about password hashing that I think at least linking to another good answer on the algorithm front would be very helpful.  Do you know of any on stackoverflow?  On the new it security stackexchange, http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/password-hashing is pretty good, so linking to it from here be the right way to help folks.

Comment: @nealmcb weak passwords are common, and adaptive cost hashing *is* a good idea. But the article suggests that a good hashing algorithm makes salting unnecessary, **which is plain wrong**. Other than that, it has some valid points, but the argumentation that leads to those points is too incomplete or tendentious. As for a good method of password hashing? use a standard library.

Comment: Yeah, the article's a bit rude, though it does indeed say that salts are important, and are in bcrypt.  Any alternative you know that clarifies how cheap brute force is now, and the need for adaptive cost plus salting, would be good.  The majority of folks asking questions about password hashing, and the majority of passwords, and the overwhelming majority of the vulnerabilities out there, are in web applications.  Most of the official standard webapp libraries I've seen are deficient in this regard: PHP, Java, Rails, MYSQL, Django.  Folks need pointers to more help....

Comment: @nealmcb 'salts are important, and are in bcrypt' is exactly the claim which is *plain wrong*.

Comment: Salts certainly are in bcrypt.  They are mixed into the key setup, as described in the paper.  128 bits worth of salt....

Comment: @nealmcb, you are confusing two concepts (as does the article, that's why it is a bad article) You should ask a separate question, these comments are now far off topic.

Comment: I admit this is an unusual thread, sorry if it seems unhelpful.  I was simply hoping, based on your request for input from security folks, to help make your very popular answer a bit better, which I think is important since most discussion of password hashing, even on stackexchange sites, is misguided.  Then after some discussion with you I fell into the trap of debating less significant issues, like why you seem to still think bcrypt doesn't have salts.  At any rate, thanks for your engagement here.  I refer interested folks to the IT Security stackexchange where we continue to work on this.

Comment: @nealcmb could you add a link to the further discussion?

Comment: See [Password hashing - IT Security - Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/password-hashing) for some good tips at the IT Security StackExchange.

Comment: One other point that is more relevant here.  You say "Technically, the salt should be unique", but that isn't strong enough.  It does also need lots of entropy as you say elsewhere.  If it was just unique, handed out by some "central organization", they might just assign sequential salts, and knowledge of how many salts had been assigned to date, or which salts had gone to your target, would reduce the attack space for a precomputed attack.

Comment: @Jacco is using the users email address as the salt a bad thing to do :D thanks

Comment: @AndyLobel, Yes! it is a very bad thing to use. Because, a) 1 user can (will) use the same email adres at two websites and b) when the user changes his/her password, the salt should also change.

Comment: @Jacco is that because an attacker could create a rainbow table for the user "example@live.co.uk" and use it on loads of different websites (including mine)?thanks

Answer (score 8):

Since Unix became popular, the right way to store a password has been to append a random value (the salt) and hash it.  Save the salt away where you can get to it later, but where you hope the bad guys won't get it.

This has some good effects.  First, the bad guys can't just make a list of expected passwords like "Password1", hash them into a rainbow table, and go through your password file looking for matches.  If you've got a good two-byte salt, they have to generate 65,536 values for each expected password, and that makes the rainbow table a lot less practical.  Second, if you can keep the salt from the bad guys who are looking at your password file, you've made it much harder to calculate possible values.  Third, you've made it impossible for the bad guys to determine if a given person uses the same password on different sites.

In order to do this, you generate a random salt.  This should generate every number in the desired range with uniform probability.  This isn't difficult; a simple linear congruential random number generator will do nicely.

If you've got complicated calculations to make the salt, you're doing it wrong.  If you calculate it based on the password, you're doing it WAY wrong.  In that case, all you're doing is complicating the hash, and not functionally adding any salt.

Nobody good at security would rely on concealing an algorithm.  Modern cryptography is based on algorithms that have been extensively tested, and in order to be extensively tested they have to be well known.  Generally, it's been found to be safer to use standard algorithms rather than rolling one's own and hoping it's good.  It doesn't matter if the code is open source or not, it's still often possible for the bad guys to analyze what a program does.

Comment: +1 for "impossible to determine if a given person uses the same password on different sites."

Answer (score 1):

You can just generate a random salt for each record at runtime. For example, say you're storing hashed user passwords in a database. You can generate an 8-character random string of lower- and uppercase alphanumeric characters at runtime, prepend that to the password, hash *that* string, and store it in the database. Since there are 62<sup>8</sup> possible salts, generating rainbow tables (for every possible salt) will be prohibitively expensive; and since you're using a unique salt for each password record, even if an attacker has generated a couple matching rainbow tables, he still won't be able to crack *every* password.

You can change the parameters of your salt generation based on your security needs; for example, you could use a longer salt, or you could generate a random string that also contains punctuation marks, to increase the number of possible salts.

Comment: You then have to store the salts in the database along with the hashed passwords, correct?

Comment: You will gain additional protection if you store the salts in a separate database, but even if they're stored alongside the hashed password, just using the salt method will significantly increase the complexity of a successful attack. The key here is that by including a random element in the hash generation process, you've made cracking ALL the passwords considerably more difficult. See this Wikipedia entry for more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29

Answer (score 0):

Use a random function generator to generate the salt, and store it in the database, make salt one per row, and store it in the database.

I like how salt is generated in django-registration. Reference: http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/tip/registration/models.py#cl-85

```
salt = sha_constructor(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:5]
activation_key = sha_constructor(salt+user.username).hexdigest()
return self.create(user=user,
           activation_key=activation_key)
```

He uses a combination of sha generated by a random number and the username to generate a hash.

`Sha` itself is well known for being strong and unbreakable. Add multiple dimensions to generate the salt itself, with random number, sha and the user specific component, **you have  unbreakable security!**

Comment: Unbreakable security? I think that is _a bit_ too optimistic.

Comment: SHA-1 is broken: http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/sha1_broken.html, so use SHA-256.

Comment: SHA-256 also become outdated now. currently suggested methods are BCrypt and PBKDF2.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a desktop application that encrypts data and send it on a remote server, how do you consider using a different salt each time?

Using PKCS#5 with the user's password, it needs a salt to generate an encryption key, to encrypt the data. I know that keep the salt hardcoded (obfuscated) in the desktop application is not a good idea.

If the remote server must NEVER know the user's password, is it possible to user different salt each time? If the user use the desktop application on another computer, how will it be able to decrypt the data on the remote server if he does not have the key (it is not hardcoded in the software) ?