# What is best possible way of salting and storing salt?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, passwords

I have read about password salting, but this might sound a little odd. But how do I store and secure the salt. For example in a multi tire architecture say I use the client machine’s GUID to generate my salt then the user gets restricted to a single machine but if I use random salt it has to be stored somewhere. Few days back I saw an sample application where the hash and the salt was generated on the client system whenever a new user was created and then the salted password and the hash is transmitted to the server where they are stored in SQL server. But if I follow this method and the database is compromised the passwords and the salt values for each password will be available to the X person. So, should I again salt/encrypt the passwords and received salt on server side? What is the best practice of salting?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Storing the salt unencrypted in the database next to the hashed passwords is not a problem.

The purpose of the salt is not to be secret. It's purpose is to be different for each hash (i.e. random), and long enough to defeat the use of [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) when an attacker gets his hands on the database.

See this [excellent post](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2007/july/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-secure-password-schemes/) on the subject by Thomas Ptacek.

**edit @ZJR**: even if the salts were completely public, they would still defeat the benefit of rainbow tables. When you have a salt and hashed data, the best you can do to reverse it is brute force (provided that the hash function is cryptographically secure)

**edit @n10i**: See the wikipedia article for [secure hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). As for the salt size, the popular [bcrypt](http://bcrypt.sourceforge.net/).gensalt() implementation uses 128 bit.

Comment: I'd say the purpose of the salt is not to be **public**, either.

Comment: can u please explain "hash function is cryptographically secure". sorry i am new to cryptography. also in your reply u mentioned "long enough to defeat the use of rainbow tables" how long should the salt be, to be long enough?

Answer (score 7):

Please take a moment to read this very good description of salts and hashing

[Salt Generation and open source software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645161/salt-generation-and-open-source-software/1645190#1645190)