# how to store password salt

Tags: mysql, passwords, md5, sha1

I've seen various methods on how to properly salt a password. The basic premise is that you attach a random string to each password before it is hashed and stored.  Can I store the salt in the same table as the password?  Also, does it matter if the salt is stored as plain text, as long as each entry has a different salt?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753028/what-is-best-possible-way-of-salting-and-storing-salt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  The idea behind a salt is not that the salt be secret, but that it causes the same password for different users to be hashed differently.  This raises the size of needed rainbow tables for cracking, or forces a dictionary (or other) attack to be ran against every password separately.

Answer (score 2):

The point of salting is that no one has the same hash as users have same password, just putting their username in front of the password then hashing it would be enough.

Comment: This can be a bad or good idea.  If you have many short usernames then the salts are too small to be useful for those particular users.

Comment: You could possibly double their username in size, anyththing specific to the user will do.

Comment: Using the username as a salt will be better than nothing, but a fully random string will be better still because it'll have more entropy. Even better would be random binary data, using the full range of bits (assuming that character data *doesn't* use the full range of bits). Better still would be to use something like PBKDF2 or bcrypt rather than a simple salted hash. And even better than that would be... etc etc.