# High performance encrypt/decrypt in both PHP AND MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, cryptography

Id like to redesign some aspects of my database/website, and am looking for reasonably strong crypto functions in PHP, which are also supported by MySQL.

I also need the encrypt/decrypt to be 100% portable & compatible

Mostly I will be crypting in PHP, selecting the crypted version from MySQL, and then decrypting in PHP.
But occasionally I will need to run a query which decrypts the field in MySQL, for reporting purposes etc

I had a look at mycrypt php library, but its not clear which of these ciphers are supported by MySQL. 
Any recommendations plase?

Comment: Have you tested any of the Mysql encryption functions(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html)?  It looks like your cypher options for compatibility are AES and DES.  I'm not sure what cypher or method Mysql's `Encode()` function uses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a bit of Google-fu it appears MySQL uses 128-bit AES with Electronic Codebook (ECB) mode. For the key, you'll need to use exactly value that's exactly 16 bytes.

Lets say I use `_My-16-byte-key_` as my secret key.

```
SELECT AES_ENCRYPT('The rooster crows at midnight!', '_My-16-byte-key_')
```

Result is: `7e41520667dc20457db2f18644bad06dd62a2120be8b93cd5596d8ffea45ef0f`

Over in PHP, I can use [mcrypt_decrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php) to reverse it:

```
$secret = '7e41520667dc20457db2f18644bad06dd62a2120be8b93cd5596d8ffea45ef0f';
$key = '_My-16-byte-key_';
print mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, pack('H*', $secret), 'ecb');
```

Result:

> The rooster crows at midnight!

I'll leave the reverse flow as an exercise to the reader. =)

Comment: Thanks for the typo fix Johan. =)

Comment: Thanks, thats really useful. I knew about AES on the MySQL side of things, but all I found for PHP was third party script or libs to use AES. Its real nice to see it can be done with vanilla PHP API

Answer (score 1):

Here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html
Is a list of all the encryption functions in MySQL.

<strike>I recommend to use AES.

All the other encryption options are no longer secure.

AES supports a 128 bit key length *(and a 256 bit key length with a recompile of the MYSQL source)*.

Don't forget [to salt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167604/how-to-store-password-salt) everything you encrypt with AES to prevent rainbow table attacks.</strike>

If you use the same key to encrypt decrypt everything all the attacker needs to do is get that key, with the hash function (and salt) you don't have to worry about losing the key, with this option you run a huge risk of losing the key and all your passwords with it.

Use a hash function instead: SHA256 with a salt.

Comment: Rainbow table attacks on AES? Citation please.

Comment: sumcbean, you are right, it's even worse. If you use the same key to encrypt decrypt everything all the attacker needs to do is get that key, with the hash function (and salt) you don't have to worry about losing the key, with this option you run a huge risk of losing the key and all your passwords with it.

Comment: Ok, but in order to get the key, and the salt, they would to have gained access to the scripts aswell as the data. If they have the scripts and the data, then really its game over already. I really dont see what measures can be taken to prevent a hacker accessing user accounts, once they have that level of access. Correct me if Im wrong though? :)

Comment: @carpii, if you use one-way hashing with a salt, even if all your data and scripts are taken your data will be much harder to decrypt and much of it will be safe. That's the thing about good crypto, even if a attacker knowns everything it's still safe. If you hash the emailaddress and the password, your attacker will have to search through a keyspace of say 8 chars + 8 chars = 16 chars. to get at usable data much harder and he cannot use rainbow tables. And this effort has be be redone for every record. Much harder than a lost key that will decrypt the whole database in one go.

Comment: thanks. I do understand what youre saying about hashing being more secure for scenarios where you just need to look up a given comparison. I already use MD5 in some places for this reason, but my particular requirements for the new features are that I do need to be able to decrypt it myself. For this reason, I must use two-way crypto rather than simply hashing algo's.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend AES, it is designed to be fast and since it is industry standard it is strong enough. However, what the reason to encrypt data inside database? If your encryption key will be stored in PHP scripts, it will not be more secure than using cleartext records. It has benefits only if many scripts access the same database.

Comment: I see your point about storing the encryption key in scripts.. but I dont agree with your comment that is it "will not be more secure than using plaintext records". An SQL Injection on plaintext would allow free access, whereas on an encrypted record it would still need to be cracked. Im not saying it would be 100% secure, but there are varying levels of security, and AES is definitely better than plaintext.