# How should I incorporate the salt in my password hash?

Tags: php, security, hash, salt

How much stronger would

```
return sha1($salt.sha1($passwd));
```

be compared to just:

```
return sha1($salt.$passwd);
```

`$salt` is a per-user string of length 12 consisting of strong random ASCII.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but why should the hash of a password be any weaker than the hash of a hash of a password? That is, as long as the hashing algorithm does what it advertises. And if it does *not*, then you shouldn't use it at all, however often.

Comment: rainbow tables (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table)

Answer (score 4):

It's exactly twice as strong, because the attacker needs to perform twice as many SHA1 calculations for a brute force attack.

Of course, that is still not exactly impressive. On the other hand, doing the SHA1 5000 times in a loop is practical for authorization, but makes attacks take 5000 times longer - this technique is known as [key strengthening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_strengthening). It is, however, really just a poor man's substitute for the adaptible-cost hash algorithms that Jacco mentions.

Comment: ...or Denial of Service, if someone spams your login form.

Comment: 5000 times SHA1 is still quicker than the DB request that you need anyway.

Answer (score 3):

At first glance, and without strong knowledge in crypto, I'd say it's not stronger at all.

By the way, it's usually advised to use

```
sha1($login.$salt.$passwd);
```

so that 2 users with the same password won't have the same hash.

Comment: Including login name in the hash solves one problem but introduces another. Now the user cannot change his/her login because it would break the hash and the hash cannot be recomputed because we don't know the user's password.

Comment: The solution to this is to generate per-user salts.

Comment: @Asaph - I'd say a major change like changing username should require them to enter their password to confirm, anyways. That way, it's available to you for recreating the hash, and another user can't change something so major as their username if they left their session open on a public computer.

Comment: Then use something unique like the user's ID in the database... Problem solved, user can change his/her name.

Comment: The very definition of salt is that it is random (random per user), so prepending the string with the login name is entirely pointless.

Comment: The "definition of salt" is not that it is random (or random per user), it is to make it harder to perform dictionary attacks by someone who has access to a copy of a hashed password database. How this is done (per user, or a single salt for a given DB) differs depending on the usage scenario. With regard to user specific information in the salt other than the username, you could use a constant, like a UID, for this purpose - though there is no intrinsic problem with two different users having the same hash value because they have the same password...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no difference in strength.

Since it is common practice to prepend the salt to the password hash, the salt is generally known to an attacker. But this does not defeat the purpose of the salt.

It is generally speaking not a a good idead to add the $login/$username to the hash ([Vinzz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043015/question-about-salt/2043030#2043030)'s solution) as it will cause problems if the user changes his or her username. A better solution is to use a *random salt*.

The used hashing algorithm *does* make a difference. `SHA1` is considered [cryptographically broken](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/sha1_broken.html) and should not be used to hash passwords.

Gennerally speaking  `BCRYPT` (a Blowfish based adaptable-cost hashing algorithm) is considdered best to be the practice (`CRYPT_BLOWFISH` flag for PHP's [crypt();](http://www.php.net/crypt))
Other solid options are  SHA256 and above.

**Edit:**
I wrote a longer answer on salting here: **[stackoverflow.com/questions/1645161/salt-generation-and-open-source-software/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645161/salt-generation-and-open-source-software/1645190#1645190)**

Comment: I didn't downvote, but IMHO it's missing the point. The question is about double-hashing a password.