# username and password validation in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

What I want to be able to do is: When a user enters their username and password in the form on the index.html page, if they match what is in the DB, then they get sent to the next page; userlogin.php.
If their username or password is incorrect then they are asked to re-enter their details on the index.html page, and displaying an error like, "Your username is Incorrect" or "Your password is Incorrect" above the form text box. I can paste this code if required.

Can I change this text font color as well, to red for example?

This is the code I currently have for the userlogin.php page

```
<?php
mysql_connect("Server", "root", "Gen") or die("Couldn't select database.");
mysql_select_db("generator") or die("Couldn't select database.");

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '$username' AND Password = '$password' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($numrows > 0)
   {
    echo 'Your in';
   }
else
   {
    echo 'Your not in';
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: Let's hope little Bobby Tables doesn't register.

Comment: Please, read about sql injection http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Jokes aside, you should learn about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Technical_Implementations) and [how to avoid it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Mitigation)

Comment: Is your application on the internet, so we can try it?

Answer (score 15):

There as sooo many things wrong with this code:

**1- you have an SQL injection hole.**

If I enter `' or 1=1 LIMIT 1 --` as a username, I will always get access, no matter what.
Change your code into.

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

See: [How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)

**2- you are storing the password in the clear**
This is a huge no no. Combined with the SQL-injection hole, it will take a hacker 5 minutes to get a list of all usernames and passwords on your site.

Store the password as a salted hash.

I like to use the username as the salt.

You store the password hash using:

```
INSERT INTO users (username, passhash) 
VALUES ('$username', SHA2(CONCAT('$password','$username'),512))
```

And you test the user credentials using:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE username = '$username' AND 
passhash = SHA2(CONCAT('$password','$username'),512)
```

See: [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)
And: [What is "salt" when relating to MYSQL sha1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351702/what-is-salt-when-relating-to-mysql-sha1)

BTW, use SHA2 with a 512 keylength, SHA1 is no longer secure, and MD5 is even more broken.

**3- A login can only ever match against 1 user**
This code:

```
if($numrows > 0)
```

Makes no sense, if you get 2 rows out of the database, that's a clear sign someone has hacked your system. The test should be:

```
if($numrows > 1) { //send email to sysadmin that my site has been hacked }
else if ($numrows = 0) { echo "wrong username or password" }
else { echo "welcome dr. Falken" }
```

**4- Don't die if there's an error, call a routine to restart the connection or something**

This code:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Is fine in testing, but in production you should do something like

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result) {
  //do the deed
} else {
  //call error recovery routine
}
```

The error recovery routine should reconnect to the server, log a error in the logbook. Is the error cannot be fixed, it should send an email to the sysadmin and only then die the server.

Comment: a side question, how safe is this: foreach ( $_GET as $id => $val )
        $_GET[$id] = mysql_real_escape_string ( $val ) ;

Comment: @Bojan, there's no problem using the $_GET in your code, there's only a problem when you insert the $_GET into an SQL or HTML string. In  the first case you need to worry about SQL-injection, in the latter you need to worry about XSS. Both problems are covered extensivly on SO, just search for `[php] [xss]` or `[php] [mysql] SQL injection` on stackoverflow.

Comment: Well i was given that by a friend and he said that that should keep it safe (along with POST one), but i'm in doubts. I know about sql injection problem, website i once made got hacked that way.. forgot to filter one input

Comment: @Bojan, if you have a question, by all means ask a question on SO, why are you using a comment to ask me a specific question without context.

Comment: I don't really think it's worth asking a question

Answer (score 2):

First of all, **your code is vulnerable to SQL injection**. Use PDO and [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to fix this. Second of all, you're appearantly storing usernames unencrypted. This is **very unsafe**. Use a [hashing function](http://php.net/manual/en/book.hash.php) to encrypt the passwords, and encrypt the submitted password before running the query to get a match. Coloring the output is simple:

```
echo '<span style="color:red">Your not in</span>';
```

And use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) to actually log the user in. After successfully querying the user table for the username/password combination, store the returned user_id in the `$_SESSION` variable. On each page that needs to be secured, just check for the existence of `$_SESSION['user_id']`; if it isn't there, your user needs to login so redirect him to the login form.

That should about do the trick for ya ;)

Comment: Using a simple user_id as a session key is a clear fail, it's a predictable integer, usually running in a sequence 1,2,3. You need to create a unique and random session_id. I would suggest using: `$session = hash('sha512', 'username'.$currentdate.$currenttime);` This will generate a unique session_id for every session, that connect be guessed.

Comment: Well, I wasn't suggesting using the user_id as a session id... I said store the user_id in the session. The session_id generated by PHP is fine.