# PHP's password_hash(): public one-time salt vs. private fixed salt

Tags: php, security, hash, passwords, salt

PHP manual for `password_hash()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) says:

> The used algorithm, cost and salt are returned as part of the hash. Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is included in it.

My question is: why?

I read this in another SO answer: ([Static Salt vs Random Salt - Security PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929251/static-salt-vs-random-salt-security-php))

> Random salts have a tremendous benefit. If all accounts in the system use the same salt, an attacker can brute-force calculate hashes for that salt and break into all accounts with just one computational run.

I get that. However, `password_hash()` embeds the salt in the returned hash, which I believe makes it public, so the salt is known to the attacker for every password.

Wouldn't it be better to have a long private salt instead?

One thing I could think of is that hashes created with the same salt would be identical for identical passwords, and possibly allow an attacker to make progress through statistical analysis of the hashes in the database.

However, this could possibly be mitigated by using a dictionary of private hashes instead of just one, but this is no longer possible with `password_hash()` in PHP 7.

I'm not a security expert, and I believe that the PHP guys know what they're doing, so I would be happy to hear why `password_hash()` way is considered to be the right way to go.

Comment: An attacker that got access to your database would probably also have access to your filesystem, being able to read the "private" salt. Having a unique salt for every hash prevents the attacker from creating a rainbow table for a specific salt and comparing it against all the hashes in your database, he has to target each hash individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this answer:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#114410

> if you thought "why is the salt included in the hash and is it save
>   when i store it as it is in my db?"
>
> Answer i found: The salt just has to be unique. It not meant to be a
>   secret.
>
> As mentioned in notes and docu before: let password_hash() take care
>   of the salt.
>
> With the unique salt you force the attacker to crack the hash. The
>   hash is unique and cannot be found at rainbow tables.