# PHP Password - Salted, reversed, encrypted

Tags: php, security, encryption, hash, passwords

I'd just like to know if this script is secure enough for a password encryption:

```
<?php

$password    = 'password';
$salt        = '9awd8n12jok1llawawf';

$new         = hash($password . $salt, 'ripemd160');
final        = strrev($new);

?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What password encryption? how valuable are the passwords? Are you handling finance?

Comment: Why reverse it? This is completely unnecessary and adds nothing to security.

Comment: No.  Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645161/salt-generation-and-open-source-software/1645190#1645190.

Comment: That depends about your salt. Is that one static?

Comment: One script can't be secure. An procedure or a system might be secure.

Comment: NO! PLEASE don't do this! Go and learn how to use bcrypt at the very least!

Comment: This question sounds like a prime candidate for [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: That's not the correct usage of [`hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the same salt for every password.  Normally what you'll want to do is use some replicable value as the salt.  For example, some hash of the user id (if the user id never changes), or some random string that you save with the user account information.  The salt should never be visible to the end user.

Comment: Just to be clear, it's not a heinous security violation if the salt is visible to the end user. It might make cracking the user's password a little easier, but as long as you're not revealing *all* salts to users, it shouldn't be a big deal. But practically speaking, there should never be a reason that the salt is visible to the end user, I'm just saying don't encode it in a cookie or anything, it should only be used server-side.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to provide even more security, store the users register timestamp and use that for a hash salt.
That way the hash salt is more random and your data a bit more secure.