# Why have a good salt?

Tags: hash, passwords, salt

Let's say we don't use `password_hash` and use `crypt()` with `sha512` instead to hash passwords. We need to add salt to the password, so an attacker couldn't use a rainbow table attack. Why the salt has to be *good* and very random as stated in many SO answers? Even if salt differs by a little or not very random, it will still give a totally different hash from others. So, an attacker won't know who uses the same passwords and he still won't be able to create just one rainbow table.

Comment: good and random salt it should be impossible to "guess" a salt.

Comment: By "good" I assume you mean "random," in which case you should read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1645190/139010), specifically "So, why does the salt have to be random?"

Comment: @Rufinus If he gets the passwords, he will get the salts.

Comment: Using user's `Id` from a row, and another more complex value, are not the same thing, as the Id may easily be guessed.

Comment: true, but thats not the reason for using random salt. see matt ball's link, better then what i can explain with a few words...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Salt Generation and open source software](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645161/salt-generation-and-open-source-software)

Comment: Hi Evening, did we answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Computing and storing a strong salt requires minimal effort yet reduces the chances of a rainbow table having being pre-computed with the salt astronomically small.

If the salt was a 3 digit number it would be feasible that an attacker could have pre-computed rainbow tables for all possible salt combinations. If the salt is a random 24 character alpha-numeric string then the chances an attacker could pre-compute this for all possible salts are practically zero.

Answer (score 2):

A salt is supposed to be unique, must be long enough, and should be unpredictable. Randomness is not necessary, but it is the easiest way for a computer to meet those requirements. And it is not the purpose of a salt to be secret, a salt fulfills its purpose even when known.

**Uniqueness** means that it should not only be unique in your database (otherwise you could use a userid), it should be unique worldwide. Somebody could create rainbowtables for salts like e.g. 1-1000 and would be able to retrieve passwords for all accounts with those userids (often admin accounts have low userids).

**Long enough**: If the salt is too short (too few possible combinations), it becomes profitable again to build rainbow-tables. Salt and password together can then be seen as just a longer password, and if you can build a rainbow-table for this longer passwords, you also get the shorter original passwords. For very strong and long passwords, salting would actually not be necessary at all, but most human generated passwords can be brute-forced because they are short (people have to remember them).

Also using salts derrived from other parameters can fall into this category. Only because you calculate a hash from the userid, this doesn't increase the possible combinations.

**Unpredictability** is a bit less important, but imagine once more the case that you use the userid as salt, an attacker can find out what the next few userids will be, and can therefore precalculate a narrow number of rainbow-tables. Depending of the used hash-algorithm this can be applicable or not. He has a time advantage then, can retrieve the password immediately. More of a problem will be, if the admin accounts used a predictable salt.

So using a really random number, generated from the OS random source (dev/urandom), is the best you can do. Even when you ignore all reasons above, why should you use a derived salt when there is a better way, why not use the best way you know?